Postgres constraint for age
I'm a bit new on Postgres's range types, and I could use your help on the following:
A person's dates of birth and death need to be recorded in a table with a daterange. To prevent invalid data, I've added a constraint alive_bounds in the table definition:
create table person (
  id bigserial not null,
  alive daterange not null,
  name text not null,
  constraint id_pkey primary key (id),
  constraint alive_bounds check (
    lower(alive) != 'infinity' and
    lower(alive) != '-infinity' and
    lower(alive) is not null and
    upper(alive) != 'infinity' and
    upper(alive) != '-infinity' and
    (coalesce(upper(alive), current_date)::timestamp
        - lower(alive)::timestamp) < interval '120 years'
  )
);
insert into person (alive, name) values (daterange(current_date, null), 'Some One');
insert into person (alive, name) values (daterange('1900-01-01', null), 'Another One');

Output:
INSERT 0 1
ERROR:  new row for relation "person" violates check constraint "alive_bounds"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, [1900-01-01,), Another One).

Aside from the warning in the docs about restoring data and using a trigger instead, the data can corrupt over time. For example within 200 years the person with ID 1 will be dead.
To test how Postgres will handle this situation, I recreated the table with the interval set to 1 second. But when I insert person 1 again, Postgres gives me no warning after the interval expired, when for example I select the data.
What is the difference with triggering a check, and this check constraint?
What better solutions are there for storing the two dates and have Postgres give some warning that the range value is or becomes invalid?

Btw, people can be older than 120 years

"Postgres gives me no warning after the interval expired, when for example I select the data." - sure, checks run only when you try to insert or update the data

"Aside from the warning in the docs …" - which of the warnings are you referring to specifically? The relevant part is "PostgreSQL assumes that CHECK constraints' conditions are immutable, that is, they will always give the same result for the same input row. This assumption is what justifies examining CHECK constraints only when rows are inserted or updated, and not at other times". You're clearly violating this by using current_date, so all bets are off. You cannot achieve your goal with constraints.

According to the dutch page, people don't get older than 120. But I'll increase the limit to 130, thanks. Your other two comments are good points. But if not with constraints, then how? The only option I see is using a trigger.

"But if not with constraints, then how?" - this is not something the database can (or imo should) do at all. You want certain records to become invalid at a certain point in time. Do you expect Postgres to just drop them at that point? You say you want to get a "warning", but how should Postgres notify you? Send you an email? Wait for the next client connection? Something else? No, this is something you need to handle in your application. A properly designed business process probably requires some manual review of these cases  anyway.

You're absolutely right, these cases require manual intervention from a user. I'll take it the responsibility of immutable checks is my own, much like the back/restore tool is required to temporarily remove constraints when restoring data, so that all rows are checked again. And in my case there is no need for creating more verbose triggers, simple checks will do the trick. Thanks again for your insights.

"I'll take it the responsibility of immutable checks is my own" - yeah tbh I'm slightly surprised Postgres doesn't enforce this, like it does enforce immutable expressions for indices etc.

A check constraint is only checked when the row is modified, not when it is selected.  The warning in the documentation is very real: if you dump your database, you might not be able to restore the dump a while later.
What would be the proper thing to do depends on what you want to happen with the row if time passes so that it becomes invalid.

If you want it to vanish from the table, the only option is a regularly scheduled job that scans the table and deletes all invalid rows.

If you are happy enough if the row becomes invisible, you could use a row-level security policy that excludes it from query results:
ALTER TABLE person ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
ALTER TABLE person FORCE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;

CREATE POLICY vanish_old ON person
   FOR ALL TO PUBLIC
   USING (coalesce(upper(alive), current_date) -
          lower(alive) < 43830);

The rows remain in the table, so if there are many, that is not a good solution.

A better, simpler solution would be to use a view on the table that just excludes the offending rows.


At any rate, remove the buggy check constraint.

The RLS policy can also lead to surprises with current_date depending on the session timezone…

I would advice to create a view to do this type of filtering. Just add a column to this view that shows you the records that might have an issue with the age of the person. If you don't show the person at all, you can't fix the problem.

@FrankHeikens That is a better idea than RLS.
